# Comparing folders with Eclipse compare APIs

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am trying to get the number of lines changed in two projects loaded into the custom project explorer. And in explorer I don't have the IResources objects.

So I am trying to construct the IResource Objects and compare as should below

```java
Resource leftResource =
        ((Workspace) ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()).newResource(new Path("c:\\temp1"), IResource.FOLDER);
Resource rightResource =
        ((Workspace) ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()).newResource(new Path("c:\\temp2"), IResource.FOLDER);

ResourceNode leftNode = new ResourceNode(leftResource);
ResourceNode rightNode = new ResourceNode(rightResource);

Object diffObject = new Differencer().findDifferences(false, null, null, null, leftNode, rightNode);
```

But the diffObject is coming as null. So what is the problem here

Comment: `Resource` and `Workspace` are **internal** classes, you should not be using them. Resource paths must be inside the workspace which neither of your paths are.

Comment: Thank you greg.  Now i am trying to create Iproject explicitly and storing this iproject into my own object. Later i am fetching the iprojects  and its resource. But still i my diffObject is coming as null<br/> IProject iProject =ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(iProjectName); <br/>iProject.create<br/>iProject.open IFolder folder =iProject.getFolder(path);<br/>folder.createLink(path,IResource.NONE,new NullProgressMonitor()); <br/> iProject1 = ((Project) paths[0].getFirstSegment()).getiProject();<br/>folder1 = iProject1.getFolder(new File(projectSelected1).getName() <br/>